# Why savepoints are not supported in Netbeans?

Tags: ms-access, netbeans, jdbc, ms-access-2007, jdbc-odbc

I have the following code

```
Savepoint sp1 = conn.setSavepoint("save");
```

which gives the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.setSavepoint(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1713)
at Transaction.TransSavePoint.main(TransSavePoint.java:32)
```

Whats wrong here

Comment: That message is from the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html), not Netbeans.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding savepoints in Netbeans-Ms Access connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837855/regarding-savepoints-in-netbeans-ms-access-connection)